# How to properly style current_page_item based from theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having hard time to figure out on how to style the menu button from http://marloncureg.com/preceptmanagement/our-services/ so that the menu item when it is the active page have a different color.

I have this custom css

```
#superfish-menu #menu-top-menu-1 .menu text-left sf-js-enabled .current_page_item .menu-item-title {
 color:#211d70!important;
}
```

but it seems I am missing out something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add the following rule in Firefox and Chrome:

```
.current_page_item .menu-item-title {
    color: red !important;
}
```

the current page item is red.

The first selector you have put there is missing the dot from the class name. Is that just a typo here?

Comment: I have i typo from my codes posted. I tried your codes and man, that works... thank you, this is the effect if you are working so hard to figure out the specific class and id to style. Thanks! :)

Comment: Usually, go with a very simple selector, and use Firebug or Developer Tools to see what's overriding it. If the selector isn't even being picked up, then it's probably a typo, but they'll be easier to spot in more simple selectors.